# R Importing table - Rows not showing properly

Tags: r

Here is my line of code...

```
xxx <- read.table(file = "/Users/xxx.txt", header = TRUE, sep=",", fill=TRUE)
```

One such column contains the following text...

```
AB#1234234324
```

My imported file is showing for that respective column as `AB`. The rest of the columns after that are appearing as `NA`.

Is there a fix for this? I reckon the issue had to do with the field containing `#`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because R is interpretating `#` as a comment, and you need to tell it otherwise.

This is done with `comment.char = ""`

For example

```
xxx <- read.table(file = "/Users/xxx.txt", header = TRUE, sep=",", fill=TRUE, comment.char = "")
```